# Trying to make my layout compatible for large phones, phablets and tablets. Can I set a maximum width for my activities/layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make my layout compatible for as many large phones, phablets and tablets. It might be my inexperience to xml layouts (too bad one can not utilize html for layouts) but on tablets which have a different aspect ratio than phones, my layout stretches out to the point of looking ugly.

I want to make it at least playble on tablets before making a design specific for tablets. Is there a way to limit the width (in dp) of my activities?

For example, if you integrate the facebook sdk into the app and the person tries to authenticate through it but does not have the facebook app, then a webview opens. This webview looks fullscreen on smaller phones, but is only basicly a layer with fixed height/width which looks like a window on big phones/tablets. I would like to do something like that, where my app does not change its width / aspect ratio no matter the screen.
I tried to put a maxWidth on my linearlayouts and it didn't have any effect, let alone the desired effect.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: thank you but this does not answer my specific question

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

I'm no expert so I may have flaws in what I'm saying but the gist is right as far as I am aware.

By the sounds of it what you'll need to do is create new drawables and layouts to actually adapt to larger sizes. using DP in xml took me a while to adjust to (being a web designer predominantly) but after a while you get used to building, essentially, four sets of layouts for everything you build, to ensure the best layout for each screen size.

If your current layout isn't looking the best on larger sizes, it sounds like you really do need to rebuild a layout using higher size objects to make sure every device gets a decent experience.

Using Maxwidth WOULD make it playable on larger devices, but would only use up a small portion of the screen when, in essence, it isn't too difficult to simply build up a new layout for the larger size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `maxWidth` View parameter, [see the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:maxWidth)

> android:maxWidth
>
> An optional argument to supply a maximum width for this view. See {see
>   android.widget.ImageView#setMaxWidth} for details.